# gridview edit mode programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a basic gridview to which I am binding the data from the code behind from a SQL stored procedure.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCheckResults" runat="server" 
        OnRowDataBound="gvCheckResults_RowDataBound" 
        RowStyle-CssClass="gridViewRow" 
        CssClass="gridView"
        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="gridViewAlternatingRow" 
        HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridViewHeader">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Databind:

```
gvCheckResults.DataSource = dataContext.GetResults(Name, Address);
gvCheckResults.DataBind();

if (!IsPostBack)
{
    //Add Edit column.
    CommandField cField = new CommandField();
    cField.EditText = "Edit";
    cField.ShowEditButton = true;
    gvCheckResults.Columns.Insert(0, cField);
}
```

How can I programmatically add Edit button to each result row?
I know how to do it when the datasource object is setup in the aspx page, but never done it programmatically.

Comment: try ItemTemplate of gridview and add the asp.net button there it will come in all the rows. and then handel its event using Row_Command event of gridview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Like this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton Id="lnkEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton Id="lnkEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"/>
        <asp:LinkButton Id="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"/>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

`OnRowEditEvent()` set the gridview edit index to `e.newrowindex` and bind it again like this.

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    //Write code TO UPDATE YOUR DATABESE THEN WRITE BELOW CODE IN LAST
    // To Find Text of TextBox to get updated value....you get it in string like this.
    //string strName = ((TextBox)grdview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[YourColumnIndexInWhichTexBoxAppear].Controls[0]).Text;
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Almost there. One weird thing is that my first 4-5 Columns all turn into Edit links. How to fix that? I want the Edit column to be the first in the gridview.

Comment: so this is the code for OnRowEditing -> `gvCheckResults.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        gvCheckResults.DataSource = dataContext.GetResults(Name,Address);
        gvCheckResults.DataBind();`

Comment: what happen when u click on edit button..show gridview aspx code

Comment: the row becomes editable (the labels turn into textboxes) and when click update it errors on `The GridView 'gvCheckResults' fired event RowUpdating which wasn't handled. ` which makes sense because there is no method for the update

Comment: ok the update works but one thing I have to fix is the Edit links which keeps taking over all my columns after every bind. See initial question for an update.

Comment: sorry i can not understand...did u put your liknbutton in itemtemplate like this....<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton Id="lnkEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"/>
</ItemTemplate>,,,,,and why you are adding link button on row databound

Comment: Sorry I have updated the main question. The code for `<ItemTemplate>` overwrites the first 3 columns in my gridview so I add the commandfield in !postback, that seems to work fine.