# how to edit the gridview programatically in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, dynamic, edit

```
  GridView gv = new GridView();

  BoundField farmername = new BoundField();
  farmername.HeaderText = "Farmer Name";
  farmername.DataField = "farmername";
  gv.Columns.Add(farmername);


  BoundField villagename = new BoundField();
  villagename.HeaderText = "Village Name";
 villagename.DataField = "village";
 gv.Columns.Add(villagename);

  BoundField feedtype = new BoundField();
  feedtype.HeaderText = "Feed Type";
  feedtype.DataField = "feedtype";
  gv.Columns.Add(feedtype);


  BoundField bf50kg = new BoundField();
  bf50kg.HeaderText = "50 Kg Bags";  
  bf50kg.DataField = "noof50kgsbags";
  gv.Columns.Add(bf50kg);

  CommandField cf = new CommandField();
  cf.ButtonType = ButtonType.Button;
  cf.ShowCancelButton = true;
  cf.ShowEditButton = true;
  gv.Columns.Add(cf);

  gv.RowEditing += new GridViewEditEventHandler(gv_RowEditing);
  gv.RowUpdating += new GridViewUpdateEventHandler(gv_RowUpdating);
  gv.RowCancelingEdit += new GridViewCancelEditEventHandler(gv_RowCancelingEdit);

  gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
  gv.ShowFooter = true;
  gv.DataSource = dtIndentDetails;
  gv.DataBind();
```

When I clicked on edit button its not spliting into update, Cancel buttons . How can I do this with command field .If I add gridview in aspx page, its splitting to update and cancel

Comment: have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206983/putting-a-gridview-row-in-edit-mode-programmatically and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280495/gridview-edit-mode-programatically

Comment: these links are not useful my code...robert can you say another way

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
protected void gridview_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
   // Change the row state
    gv.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried your code and found it working. 
Take care of below points:

1.) The Code creating GridView (and all fields ) should be executed every time. Means remove any `!IsPostback` condition from this code, If present any.

2.) In your `RowEditing`  event of your gridview set the editindex and rebind the gridview.

```
protected void gv_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = sender as GridView;
        gv.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        gv.DataBind();
    }
```