# Error while trying to get text value from textbox in C# (ASP.NET gridview)

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

When I'm trying to get a value from a textbox I keep getting this error (see image) and I don't know how to fix it. I'm using the following code:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _controller = new Controller();

        //Variablen
        string afspraak ="";

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            afspraak = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtEditTabel")).Text;               
        }
```

I'm using javascript combined with ASP.NET and the code looks like this;
more info about the js: [EDITABLE LABEL](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Editable-Label-Convert-a-Label-to-TextBox-when-clicked-using-jQuery-in-ASPNet.aspx)

**JAVASCRIPT** (it changes a label to a textbox on click)

```
$(function () {
//Loop through all Labels with class 'editable'.
$(".editable").each(function () {
    //Reference the Label.
    var label = $(this);

    //Add a TextBox next to the Label.
    label.after("<input type = 'text' style = 'display:none' />");

    //Reference the TextBox.
    var textbox = $(this).next();

    //Set the name attribute of the TextBox.
    var id = this.id.split('_')[this.id.split('_').length - 1];
    //textbox[0].name = id.replace("Label","Textbox"); //tis dit hier van die id's
    textbox[0].name = "txtEditTabel";
    //Assign the value of Label to TextBox.
    textbox.val(label.html());

    //When Label is clicked, hide Label and show TextBox.
    label.click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next().show();
    });

    //When focus is lost from TextBox, hide TextBox and show Label.
    textbox.focusout(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).prev().html($(this).val());
        $(this).prev().show();
    });
});
```

});

**ASP.NET**

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="1000px" HorizontalAlign="Center" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IDAfspraken">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IDAfspraken") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
          </asp:GridView>
```

**I'm 100% sure that my SQL code is correct. Am I missing something? I'd really appreciate the help!**

Error:
[image: Error image]

Comment: Why not simple define an Edit Template for your Grid? I think you are way over-complicating things mixing asp.net and hand-built client-side code here. See [gridview edit mode programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16280495/205233) for example.

Answer (score 0):

The value for `((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtEditTabel"))` appears to be returning a null or undefined value, hence the NullPointerException, when trying to dereference the `.Text` property.

Your use case seems really specific to your C# code, moreso than the JavaScript. My best guess is that you should try adding an `id` property to your control rather than a name. I could be wrong, but judging by the specs [found here on FindControl method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx), you should be accessing the control by ID instead of name.

Edit:
If your input is inside of a form, try accessing it via the input's name property with the following syntax: `Request.Form["txtName"];` instead of trying to do a `FindControl`.